# ios how to get alertview-button action from OneSignal notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, onesignal

[image: how to get notification Alert action event handler ?]

- In AppDelegate.m

  [OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions appId:@"put app ID here." handleNotificationReceived:^(OSNotification *notification) {
          NSLog(@"Received Notification - %@", notification.payload.notificationID);
      } handleNotificationAction:^(OSNotificationOpenedResult *result) {

  ```
      // This block gets called when the user reacts to a notification received
      OSNotificationPayload* payload = result.notification.payload;

      NSString* messageTitle = @"OneSignal Example";
      NSString* fullMessage = [payload.body copy];

      if (payload.additionalData) {

          if(payload.title)
              messageTitle = payload.title;

          if (result.action.actionID)
              fullMessage = [fullMessage stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nPressed ButtonId:%@", result.action.actionID]];
      }
  } settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption : @(OSNotificationDisplayTypeNotification), kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : @YES}];

  [OneSignal IdsAvailable:^(NSString *userId, NSString *pushToken) {
      if(pushToken) {
          NSLog(@"Received push token - %@", pushToken);
          NSLog(@"User ID - %@", userId);
      }
     }];
  ```

  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    }

Comment: Please add some more details information.

Comment: Describe the problem and the code..what you tried

Comment: whenever i receive notification alert, then i want to redirect to web browser but i can not able to get delegate action of alertview which is come from the OneSignal notification. how to handle alertview delegate ? @suraj.